# Trouble with gitlab updating on redhat 8: nothing provides perl

Tags: perl, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I've in trouble with updating GitLab CE 15.0.x -> 15.4.0

```
dnf install gitlab-ce-15.4.0
```

> conflicting requests
>
> - nothing provides perl needed by gitlab-ce-15.4.0-ce.0.el8.x86_64
>   (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only > best candidate packages)

```
dnf install perl
```

> 未找到匹配的参数： perl # no match parameters
>
> 错误：没有任何匹配 # error: no any match

**I've searched a lot and I can't find a specific solution for this, it seems like in redhat8 the name of perl is perl-interpreter**

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core) 

# dnf list perl-interpreter
已安装的软件包 // installed packages
perl-interpreter.x86_64                          4:5.26.3-416.el8                          @anaconda
可安装的软件包 // installable packages
perl-interpreter.x86_64                          4:5.26.3-420.el8                          base
```

Comment: What is the output of running `yum info perl` ?

Comment: 错误：没有匹配的软件包可以列出 （Error: no matching packages to list）